# How to create a function which return a boolean depending on a select statement result

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql, select-case

I have a table(Id, FK, Date1, Date2) and I need to create a function that will return a boolean value. Generally I want to select records with matching the given FK and check some additional statements. I want to return true if the select statement returns 0 rows and false otherwise. I've already written this code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION isAlreadyTaken(FK INT4, Date1 DATE, Date2 DATE)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN
AS $$
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMP TABLE helper ON COMMIT DROP AS SELECT COUNT(table.FK) AS quant 
    FROM table
    WHERE table.FK = FK AND table.Date2 IS NULL;
  SELECT CASE
    WHEN helper.quant > 0
    THEN FALSE
    ELSE TRUE 
  END;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The code is compiling, and can be executed. But when I invoke the function in CHECK statement it returns an ERROR [42P01]. Is the solution near the actually working one, or I've completely lost my way ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`COUNT(...) > 0 WHERE ...` is equivalent to `EXISTS(select ... where ...)` , and
`EXISTS(table expression)` *already* yields a boolean:

```
EXISTS (
 SELECT *
 FROM table t
 WHERE t.FK = FK AND t.Date2 IS NULL
 )
```

---

Putting that into your query (Note the Date1 and Date2 arguments appear to be unused...)

```
CREATE FUNCTION isAlreadyTaken1(FK INT4, Date1 DATE, Date2 DATE)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table t
    WHERE t.FK = FK 
         AND t.Date2 IS NULL    -- <<-- this looks nonsensical
        );
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

And, as @a_horse_with_no_name commented: you don't even need plpgsql, just plain SQL will do:

```
CREATE FUNCTION isAlreadyTaken1a(FK INT4, Date1 DATE, Date2 DATE)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN
AS $func$
  SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table t
    WHERE t.FK = FK
         AND t.Date2 IS NULL    -- <<-- this looks nonsensical
        );
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

---

BTW: I inverted the logic. IMO *allreadyTaken* means `count() > 0`.

Comment: You don't even need PL/pgSQL for this, a plain `sql` function will do

Comment: That is correct. *or maybe even a subquery-term in a while clause*

Comment: `return true if the select statement returns 0 rows and false otherwise.` sounds like `NOT EXISTS (...)`

Comment: `isAlreadyTaken1a()` seems to imply `EXISTS()` I don't kwow the OP's intentions, but adding a NOT seems within his ability. BTW: thanks for the edit.